# HTTP Request Format

Tags: http, http-headers, rfc

I read from RFC2616 section 14.23 :

```
 Host = "Host" ":" host [ ":" port ] ; Section 3.2.2
```

but the examples is :

```
   GET /pub/WWW/ HTTP/1.1
   Host: www.w3.org
```

why there is a space between ":" and the url, I use firebug and chrome inspect element and found all the request in the http header, between the key and value, there is a space. According to the RFC, there isn't. How to explain this ? the space is necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the HTTP/1.1 RFC, white space between the colon and the field value is not required however a single white space is preferred. Any white space between the colon and the first non-whitespace character is not included in the field value. Read it here in section 4.2: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html

Comment: This is made more explicit in httpbis - see https://svn.tools.ietf.org/svn/wg/httpbis/draft-ietf-httpbis/latest/p1-messaging.html#header.fields